# How to get a specific element from a for-loop into a separate array using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently working on something and hit a brick wall so thought I'd ask for some help.

I'm trying to implement an onclick feature in which a user can click on an image that was produced by a for-loop, and then add the selected image's ID to a separate array which will be implemented later in a form (using JSON.stringify) and sent to the back-end for processing. Currently, this is what I have:

```
function displayImages(testdata) {
    // the container
    var container = document.getElementById('content');

    for (var i = 0; i < testdata.length; i++) {
      
        // create the image element
        var imageElement = document.createElement('img');
    

        //add image filepath to each image
        imageElement.src = testdata[i].filepathOriginal;
        //add the imageID to each of the images
        imageElement.id = testdata[i].imageID;
        //styling in JS //
        imageElement.height = 160;
        imageElement.width = 160;
        imageElement.style.flexDirection = "row"; 
        

        
       // append the element to the container
        container.appendChild(imageElement);
    }
}

//JS to add images that user selects to array

function addToArr(item){

    var sList = [];
    var index = sList.indexOf(item);
    if (index == -1) { //if not already added as 0 is the first image
      sList.push(item) // add to array
    }

    sList.forEach(function (){
        imageElement.onclick = function(){ addToArr(imageElement.id); } // <-- this line
        });
      

    //JSON.stringify loads the array into readable format for next stage
    document.getElementById('list').value = JSON.stringify(sList);
    console.log("Images selected by user are: " + JSON.stringify(sList));
  }
```

I thought adding the foreach would help me out but it didn't do anything. The other issue I had was I tried adding a code to call the addToArray function inside the for-loop, but this just added the final element that was being iterated through...

Would love some help on this as I'm sure I'm missing something obvious :)

P.S
In-case you needed to see the testdata array:

```
 //TEST DATA!!!
    var testdata = [
      {
          "imageID": 17,
          "uploadedDate": "2020-07-31 03:56:56.243139",
          "filepathOriginal": "test_images/testimage1.jpg"
      },
      {
          "imageID": 18,
          "uploadedDate": "2020-07-31 04:06:14.711057",
          "filepathOriginal": "test_images/testimage2.jpg"
      },
      {
          "imageID": 19,
          "uploadedDate": "2020-07-31 04:08:10.360168",
          "filepathOriginal": "test_images/testimage3.jpg"
      }
    ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add image by clicking on it use:

```js
imageElement.onclick = (e) => {
  addToArr(imageElement);
};
```

Example:

```js
//TEST DATA!!!
var testdata = [{
    "imageID": 17,
    "uploadedDate": "2020-07-31 03:56:56.243139",
    "filepathOriginal": "test_images/testimage1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "imageID": 18,
    "uploadedDate": "2020-07-31 04:06:14.711057",
    "filepathOriginal": "test_images/testimage2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "imageID": 19,
    "uploadedDate": "2020-07-31 04:08:10.360168",
    "filepathOriginal": "test_images/testimage3.jpg"
  }
];

var sList = [];

function displayImages(testdata) {
  // the container
  var container = document.getElementById('content');

  for (var i = 0; i < testdata.length; i++) {

    // create the image element
    let imageElement = document.createElement('img');


    //add image filepath to each image
    imageElement.src = testdata[i].filepathOriginal;
    //add the imageID to each of the images
    imageElement.id = testdata[i].imageID;
    //styling in JS //
    imageElement.height = 160;
    imageElement.width = 160;
    imageElement.style.flexDirection = "row";

    imageElement.onclick = (e) => {
      addToArr(imageElement);
    };

    // append the element to the container
    container.appendChild(imageElement);
  }
}

//JS to add images that user selects to array
function addToArr(item) {

  var index = sList.indexOf(item.id);
  if (index == -1) { //if not already added
    sList.push(item.id) // add to array
  }

  //JSON.stringify loads the array into readable format for next stage
  document.getElementById('list').value = JSON.stringify(sList);
  console.log("Images selected by user are: " + JSON.stringify(sList));
}

// TEST
displayImages(testdata);
```

```html
<input id="list" type="text" />
<div id="content"></div>
```